# Justification for $u$-substitution method

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am currently learning how to find antiderivatives using the "$u$-substitution" or "integration by substitution" method. A key component of this is setting some expression in the indefinite integral as "$u$", and then also finding $du/dx$.

How can we then write $du = dx \cdot $ (some expression)? Isn't $du/dx$ defined as the derivative of $u$ and is not a fraction?

Comment: $du = dx * [\text{expression}]$ is just notation. More accurately: $\int f(u(x)) du(x) = \int f(u(x)) \frac{du}{dx} dx$, and since the $f(u(x))$ stays the same, it can be easier to explain by saying that $du(x) = \frac{du}{dx} dx$, and the fact that $u$ is a function of $x$ is then omitted from the notation, giving that $du = \frac{du}{dx} dx$. In short -- it's not quite correct (Though there is something that looks similar and is correct in the language of differential forms), but it is a simple way of explaining things if you don't think too hard about it.

Answer (score 2):

From a simplistic viewpoint, you can view this as a convenient mnemonic: a notation that helps you remember what's true. Once you've learned that, given dependent variables $u$ and $x$ that satisfy $u = g(x)$, you can choose the antiderivatives so that

$$ \int f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u = \int f(g(x)) g'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

then it is much easier to *remember* the rule via implicit differentiation of differentials: that $\mathrm{d}u = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} \, \mathrm{d}x$.

From a deeper viewpoint, once you recognize the patterns going on here, you'll want to form a concept of a differential $\mathrm{d}x$ as a new kind of mathematical object that really exists, and is something you can manipulate.

One can then define an integral not to be the integral of a function, or as the integral of an expression with respect to one of its variables, but instead you take integrals of differentials.

From this more sophisticated viewpoint, that's what integrals are *supposed* to be, and that the integral you learned in introductory calculus was just a simplification that is easier to teach and requires less sophistication to discuss rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view it is better to think of substituting $x$ by $x(u)$. The substitution, however, changes the shape of the function and therefore the integral. The picture below illustrates this fact. There is graphical approach to show why you need a special replacement of $dx$: You can think of compensating for the density by multiplying by it, namely $dx/du$. However, you may find it helpful to read the full explanation on [Insight Things](http://www.insight-things.com/integration-substitution).

[image: What happens when you substitute]